# in pop up window i want to create dynamic element but class cast exception is coming in addNewRow nethod

Tags: android, xml

This is my code.Here i want to add some dynamic element like check box,edit text but in add new row is throwing error class cast exception and also pop up is not creating.

```
private void _claculateSalesReturn(Cursor srCur){
        View srLayout = _initiateSalesReturnPopupWindow();
        int rowCount = 0;
        if(srLayout != null){
            ImageView btnClosePopup = (ImageView) srLayout.findViewById(R.id.btn_close_popup);
            btnClosePopup.setOnClickListener(new   UUIHandlers.UListener(this,BILL_SALES_RETURN_POPUP_CLOSE));



//setContentView(R.layout.sales_return_popup);
            TableLayout salesReturnTableEle = (TableLayout) srLayout.findViewById(R.id.salesReturnTable);
            int tableID = salesReturnTableEle.getId();

            srTable = new UTable(this, tableID);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams trparams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
           // tr.setLayoutParams(trparams);
            salesReturnTableEle.setLayoutParams(trparams);

            float eleWeights[] = {.02f, .68f};
            if(null != srCur){
               while (srCur.moveToNext()) {

                int srId = srCur.getInt(srCur.getColumnIndex("srID"));
                double srAmt = srCur.getDouble(srCur.getColumnIndex("salesReturnAmt"));


                View rowData[] = new View[2];

                CheckBox checkBox = _createCheckboxElement(srId, eleWeights[0], false, R.color.text_background_color, Typeface.NORMAL);
                //checkBox.setOnClickListener(new UUIHandlers.UListener(this, ACTION_ASSET_SELECTED));
                rowData[0] = checkBox;


                rowData[1] = _createSrAmtElement(String.valueOf(srAmt),eleWeights[1]);

                //TableRow tableRow = srTable.addNewRow(rowData,trparams);
                TableRow tableRow = srTable.addNewRow(rowData,trparams, salesReturnTableEle);

                rowCount++;


            }
         }
        }
    }


private View _initiateSalesReturnPopupWindow() {
        int xCoOrdinate = 25;
        int yCoOrdinate = 25;
        int xWindowPerc = 10;
        int yWindowPerc = 50;
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth();  
        int height = display.getHeight();
        View layout = null;

        xCoOrdinate = ((width*xWindowPerc)/100);
        yCoOrdinate = ((height*yWindowPerc)/100);
        width = width - xCoOrdinate;
        height = height - yCoOrdinate;

        try {
            // We need to get the instance of the LayoutInflater
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sales_return_popup, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.salesReturnPopupWindow));

            srPopUpWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height, true);
            srPopUpWindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.AXIS_X_SHIFT,(xCoOrdinate/2), (yCoOrdinate/2));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error while initiation of the sales return Popup."  + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return layout;
    }
```

this is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/salesReturnPopupWindow"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_window_background"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/saleReturnTable"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/discAmtRow"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView"
                style="@style/textview_style"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".99"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/sales_return_popup_header"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/btn_close_popup"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight=".01"
                android:src="@drawable/popup_cancel" />
        </TableRow>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/sku_search_bottom_seperator"
            style="@style/seperator_style"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />
    </TableLayout>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="95"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="95">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/salesReturnTable"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

This is my uTable :

```
public UTable(UActivity uActivity, int tableLayoutID) {
        this.uActivity = uActivity;
        //this.tableLayoutID = tableLayoutID;
        tableLayout = (TableLayout)uActivity.findViewById(tableLayoutID);
    }

This is my addNewRow:

  public TableRow addNewRow(View[] rowData, TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams, TableLayout tableLayout) {
        /* the value of the variable always should incremented as we will use this to generate
         * unique id for the row elements */
        maxRowCount ++;

        int rowID = maxRowCount * ROW_ID_INCREMENT_FACTOR;

        TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(uActivity);
        tableRow.setId(rowID);

        for(int i = 0, elementID = 1; i < rowData.length; i++, elementID++){
            View child = rowData[i];
            if(child != null){
                child.setId(rowID + elementID);
                   tableRow.addView(rowData[i]);
            }
        }

        /* adding table row to the table layout*/
        tableLayout.addView(tableRow,tableRowParams);

        /* the value of the variable always should incremented as we will use this to generate
         * unique id for the row elements */
        //maxRowCount++;
        return tableRow;
    }
```

LOG CAT:

```
10-14 12:26:31.583: D/AndroidRuntime(17982): Shutting down VM
10-14 12:26:31.583: W/dalvikvm(17982): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TableLayout$LayoutParams
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:288)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1205)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.onLayout(HorizontalScrollView.java:1204)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-14 12:26:31.693: E/AndroidRuntime(17982):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Layout params of a view must be compatible with the view's parent.

Your `TableLayout` is in a `LinearLayout`, so you should be using `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` for the `TableLayout`.

In your code the `TableLayout.LayoutParams` actually don't change anything in the layout so you can remove the `setLayoutParams()` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `R.id.salesReturnTable` with `R.id.saleReturnTable`